# Django error "home.models.Friend.DoesNotExist: Friend matching query does not exist."

Tags: python, django

My project was working fine until I had to uninstall and reinstall the MySQL database and re-migrate / re-create the data.

Now when I navigate to `/home/` it throws this error

```
DoesNotExist at /home/
Friend matching query does not exist.
```

The query does exist in the database and all other pages work.

From the command line:

```
 Internal Server Error: /home/
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/trillav/.virtualenvs/max/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/Users/trillav/.virtualenvs/max/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "/Users/trillav/.virtualenvs/max/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "/Users/trillav/.virtualenvs/max/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 68, in view
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/trillav/.virtualenvs/max/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 88, in dispatch
        return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/trillav/apps/max/home/views.py", line 16, in get
        friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
      File "/Users/trillav/.virtualenvs/max/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/trillav/.virtualenvs/max/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 399, in get
        self.model._meta.object_name
    home.models.Friend.DoesNotExist: Friend matching query does not exist.
    [31/Oct/2018 13:53:02] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 500 81063
```

Here is `home.models`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Post(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Friend(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='owner', null=True)

    @classmethod
    def make_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        friend.users.add(new_friend)

    @classmethod
    def lose_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
        friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            current_user=current_user
        )
        friend.users.remove(new_friend)
```

And my home view function:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from home.forms import HomeForm
from home.models import Post, Friend

# Create your views here.
class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'home/home.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = HomeForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
        friends = friend.users.all()

        args = {
            'form': form, 'posts': posts, 'users': users, 'friends': friends
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def post(self, request):
        form = HomeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.user = request.user
            post.save()
            text = form.cleaned_data['post']
        return redirect('home:home')

        args = {'form': form, 'text': text}
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def change_friends(request, operation, pk):
    friend = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if operation == 'add':
        Friend.make_friend(request.user, friend)
    elif operation == 'remove':
        Friend.lose_friend(request.user, friend)
    return redirect('home:home')
```

What is causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's your view function for `/home/`?

Comment: Have you tried to add `print(request.user)` in the view, so you can confirm which value it has?

Comment: @Chris I've just added it

Comment: @Ralf If I add `print(request.user)` I would still be unable to see it right because of the error?

Comment: @Trillz No, in your console (where all the output of the server is printed) there should be the output of that print statement, most likely just before the error.

Comment: @Ralf Hmm, I've just tried adding it to the view but no change in the console output message, where exactly should I add it?

Comment: @Trillz it has to be put in your view just before the line `friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)`, because that lines throws the error (according to your error stacktrace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 16 in `views.py` is mentioned in your traceback. Here's what it says:

```
friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
```

A `Manager`'s [`get` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) is intended to retrieve exactly one object:

> If you know there is only one object that matches your query, you can use the [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) method on a [`Manager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/managers/#django.db.models.Manager) which returns the object directly

If your query retrieves any other number of objects an exception will be raised (a model-specific subclass of `DoesNotExist`—`Friend.DoesNotExist` here—if zero objects are returned and a subclass of `MultipleObjectsReturned` if more than one is returned).

I suspect you want users to be able to have zero friends, or more than one friend? Instead of `get()`, use the [`filter()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter):

```
friends = Friend.objects.filter(current_user=request.user)
```

This will work no matter how many friends the `current_user` has.

Comment: Ah yes of course, thank you very much. That has fixed that error however now I get `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'users'` which looks like it corresponds with `File "/Users/trillav/apps/max/home/views.py", line 17, in get
    friends = friend.users.all()`

Comment: @Trillz, now that users can have multiple `Friend`s (they always could at the ORM level; your view code just didn't support it) you're getting `n` `Friend`s from that query. You can't assume you only have one; note that I changed the name of the variable from `friend` to `friends` in my version. You'll have to update your logic to deal with a list of users (well, technically a `QuerySet`, but you can loop over it, for example), and I don't have the domain-specific context to tell you how to best do that. You could also build a new query from it.

Comment: I am still a beginner so I need to do some further study before I can properly implement your answer but thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.